# Sending post information to a coldfusion site.

Tags: sharing

I have a requirement where I need to send the post title, excerpt and permalink to an external coldfusion site. Basically, the coldfusion site would display this information as a teaser and then allow the reader to click on the permalink to go to the wordpress post page to read more.

Is there a web service available that can help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go with WebHooks (or something similar). »Mitcho« already designed a plugin for that, called [HookPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hookpress/).

> Webhooks are a simple paradigm for developing instant notifications and mashups based on simple HTTP requests. With HookPress you can set up webhooks so that a specified URL (a public service or something you set up) is requested when certain WordPress actions occur. Possible uses include generating push notifications or using non-PHP web technology to extend WordPress.

### Video:

[HookPress: add webhooks to WordPress](http://vimeo.com/5905102) from [mitcho](http://vimeo.com/mitcho) on [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com).